# Why default Equals method implementation for structs uses reflection?

Tags: c#, struct, default, equals

If at least 1 struct field is of reference type, default `Equals` method implementation for this struct uses reflection to call `Equals` for each field.

Reflection at run-time is very heavy. Why not just autogenerate default `Equals` method for such structs while compiling to avoid run-time reflection using?

Comment: Where have you seen that code?

Comment: @Julian, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs. (also corrected the question a little)

Comment: I see also indeed "If none of the fields of the current instance and obj are reference types, the Equals method performs a byte-by-byte comparison of the two objects in memory. Otherwise, it uses reflection to compare the corresponding fields of obj and this instance." From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I think because the concrete type is not always known at compile time so it has to do this at runtime.

Comment: I believe the hope is that `Equals` will be overridden in those cases and thus it was likely deemed not to be a worth wild feature to implement.  But really only the C# designers can definitively answer why they choose to implement something one way or the other.

Comment: You are stating: Reflection at run-time is very heavy. I believe you can leave the word "very"out and you really need to think if the overhead of reflection is an issue for you..

Comment: The duplicate was found by Googling for `Why default Equals method implementation for structs uses reflection?`.

Comment: `Why not just autogenerate` I've found https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/ a helpful article for thinking through why stuff isn't done.